# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209) Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path ='./data/filename.mvt'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to read the data from .mvt file by using the below code

```
@override
  Future<DatastoreReadResult?> readLabelsSingle(Tile tile) async {
    VectorTile tiles = await VectorTile.fromPath(path: './mapsforge_flutter/lib/src/data/6160.mvt');
    VectorTileLayer layer =
        tiles.layers.firstWhere((layer) => layer.name == 'building');
    layer.features.forEach((feature) {
      feature.decodeGeometry();
      if (feature.geometryType == GeometryType.Point) {
        var geojson = feature.toGeoJson<GeoJsonPoint>(x: 4823, y: 6160, z: 14);

        print(geojson?.type);
        print(geojson?.properties);
        print(geojson?.geometry?.type);
        print(geojson?.geometry?.coordinates);
        print('\n');
      }
    });
```

but after running the code i am getting bellow error

> E/flutter ( 1225): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = './mapsforge_flutter/lib/src/data/6160.mvt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

My folder structure are as below which are on my desktop

```
mapsforge_flutter 
└───mapsforge_flutter
    └───lib
        └───src
            └───data(file is here)
```

Please help me to resolve the error